# How to populate rows where a key word exists

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to add a boolean of true to specific elements within a column called `exempt_from_discount`, for simplicity sake and for my understanding lets just say where `school` or anything child related appears I would like to make the `exempt_from_discount` true. So far the table looks like the following:

[image]

My initial thought was to write a query that sets all the elements to false by the following via my migration:

```
ALTER TABLE ticket_types
  ALTER exempt_from_discount SET DEFAULT false;
```

And then once this is done set each one that contains `school`/is based on a child to true. I am limited on knowledge regarding SQL and am not sure how this would be achieved (Bare in mind this is only about 1/4 of the table so doing it manually per row might not be the best with efficiency in hindsight.). I am greatfull for any input/hints as I am eager to learn more about SQL.

Comment: Correct-a-mundo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UPDATE` to change values

```
UPDATE ticket_types
  SET exempt_from_discount = FALSE
WHERE TRUE
```

Set the where condition accordingly.